My Wordpress php code snippets not working
I trying to use this snippet to prevent anyone who doesn't has a specific word in his username to describe the device he use to login into the website from using the website
this code is not doing anything at all , I'm using a plugin called "code snippets"
<?php
if( is_front_page() ) {
$userag = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$usern = $current_user->user_login;
$appleAgent = str_contains($userag, "Mac");
$appleIos = str_contains($usern, "ios");
$appleMac = str_contains($usern, "mac");
if( ($appleAgent == 1 && $appleMac == 1)     ||  ($appleAgent == 1 && $appleIos == 1)  ){
  echo "";
}elseif( ($appleAgent == FALSE && $appleIos == FALSE && $appleMac == FALSE) ){
  echo "";
}else{  echo "<script>location.href='https://www.google.com/';</script>"; }
}
?>

is there any way to make this work?

Side note (not solving your problem): you don't need ==1 and == FALSE when you have a boolean, just if ( ($appleAgent && $appleMac) || ... ) and if(! $appleAgent && ! $appleMac && ... )

More relevant to your problem: where is this code snippet running? It's trying to echo out some JS to the page, to tell the browser to redirect, but where in the page is that going to be output?
